# 500 URL rewrite error for relative URLs. Is there something wrong with my outbound IIS rewrite rule?

Tags: regex, url-rewriting, iis-7, outbound

I am having a bit of difficulty achieving an outbound rewrite rule in IIS 7 and was wondering if anybody would be able to double check my rules?

The purpose of this outbound rule is to rewrite any a href="www.domain.com" to go to a href="/__tracking/pre_processing.php" (a script which does some tracking before we send the user on their way to domain.com). The outbound rule also attempts to preserve any query strings so that domain.com?p=100&q=200 can be rewritten to /__tracking/pre_processing.php?p=100&q=200

```
    <rewrite>
        <outboundRules>
            <rule name="Outbound Rewrite test" preCondition="" enabled="false">
                <match filterByTags="A" pattern="domain\.com(.*|\?.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" value="/__tracking/pre_processing.php{R:1}" />
                <conditions>
                </conditions>
            </rule>
        </outboundRules>
    </rewrite>
```

It sounded simple enough yet when I enabled the rule, js and css assets weren't loading and web inspector told me I was getting a 500 URL rewrite error on things such as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Common/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Common/script.js">
```

The rule did work however, every a href="domain.com" was rewritten to go to my tracking script but then I got all these 500 errors. Can anybody fill me in on what I'm missing? Much appreciated

Comment: A colleague was able to point out what was wrong. Since outbound rules apply to all server requests, we need to set preconditions so that this rule only content type text/html. This is probably what was causing the 500s on the js and css assets. So the following precondition worked

    <preConditions>
        <preCondition name="IsHTML">
        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
        </preCondition>
    </preConditions>

Comment: It is best to post that as an answer for future reference. Thanks.